# como realizar una consulta con una lista pasándola como parámetro a un store procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un store procedure que es el siguiente:

```
procedure [dbo].[proc_consulta_sap]
(
@UsuariosABuscar varchar (8000)
)
as
select Ambiente from SAP
whERE ID =@UsuariosABuscar
```

cuando consulto con un `string` por ejemplo **`"ec0664"`** el store se ejecuta correctamente. lo que yo quiero es como ejecutarlo con una lista de `string` por ejemplo, `"ec0664,ec0665,ec0666"` el cual cargo a través de un textbox multiline. con cada uno de esos realizar la consulta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Sql-Server estás utilizando? Porque te recomendaría que utilices [Parámetros de Tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) para pasar varios valores. Avísame así respondo con un ejemplo sencillo de enviar id's cómo estás enviando ahora. Porque ahora envías texto plano que es un cvs.

Comment: buenas, estoy usando sql server 2017 express!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos formas clásicas y una más moderna:

#### 1. Pasando una cadena de valores separado por comas

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_consulta_sap] (
    @UsuariosABuscar VARCHAR (8000)
) AS

    SELECT  @UsuariosABuscar = ',' + @UsuariosABuscar ','
    SELECT  Ambiente FROM SAP
        WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + ID + ',',  @UsuariosABuscar) > 0
```

Básicamente vemos si la cadena `,<ID>,` se encuentra en otra cadena que pasamos como parámetro del estilo `<ID1>,<ID2>,<ID3>`, Muy importante asegurarnos que la búsqueda incluya siempre las comas de inicio y fin, para evitar problemas cuando buscas `1` en una lista que sea por ejemplo: `10,11,12`. Esta solución está limitada a la cantidad de `ID` más las comas que puedas llegar a indicar en el tamaño del parámetro `@UsuariosABuscar`. Además este tipo de consultas no suele ser del todo óptima ya que desaprovecha eventualmente el uso de índices.

#### 2. Pasar los valores a buscar por medio de una tabla temporal

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_consulta_sap]
AS

    SELECT  Ambiente FROM SAP
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT Usuario FROM #Tmp_Ususarios)

CREATE TABLE #Tmp_Ususarios (Usuario VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO #Tmp_Ususarios (Usuario)
    VALUES ('ec0664'),('ec0665'),('ec0666')

EXEC proc_consulta_sap
DROP TABLE Tmp_Ususarios
```

Esta es la forma adecuada en general para pasar múltiples valores a cualquier SP. 
Insertamos en una temporal los valores a buscar y en la misma conexión invocamos al SP.

#### 3. Parámetros tipo tabla

Una forma similar a la anterior, pero más moderna, es usar los [parámetros de tipo tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

```
-- Creamos el tipo de dato para el parámetro
CREATE TYPE UsusariosBuscar AS TABLE (Usuario VARCHAR(15));  
GO  

-- Creamos el sp
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_consulta_sap] (
    @UsuariosABuscar UsusariosBuscar READONLY
) AS

    SELECT  Ambiente FROM SAP
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT Usuario FROM @UsuariosABuscar)


DECLARE @UsuariosABuscar AS UsusariosBuscar;  

-- Agregamos los casos a la variable
INSERT INTO @UsuariosABuscar (Usuario)  
    VALUES ('ec0664'),('ec0665'),('ec0666')

EXEC proc_consulta_sap @UsuariosABuscar
```

Comment: mil gracias patricio!. me ayudaron y terminé optando por la opción 2,

Answer (score 1):

cuando haces

```
Where id = valor
```

Le estas diciendo a la query que busque filas donde id sea exactamente igual a valor.

Si vos queres usar una lista de valores y que entonces se compare el valor de un campo para ver si esta en una lista, se usa el operador [`IN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Where id IN (lista de valores separadas por coma)
```

Tene en cuenta, que sirve tambien para un valor, y que esa lista tiene un tope segun la db que estes usando.

Cuando el motor encuentra la clausula `IN`, la transforma en

```
Where id = valor1 or id = valor2 or id = valor3 etc
```

Comment: no quiero buscarlo en una lista, lo que quiero es con una lista de elementos realizar la query con cada uno de los elementos de la lista

Comment: @FernandoPerez No entiendo la diferencia. Pero en ese caso, porque no mandas los codigos de a uno y listo? porque entonces no se termina de entender que queres.

Comment: ahi estuve viendo y parece que si me conviene mandarlos de a uno, el tema esta en como los puedo ir mostrando

Comment: @FernandoPerez es que me parece que tu problema es otro, no el que mostraste aca. que tiene que ver mostrarlos con esto?